# Conditionally replicate rows of a tabular data file based on value in a column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a large csv file with the following structure:

```
col1,col2,codes
1,2,aaa__bbb
2,4,aaa__eee
3,4,ccc
```

Column 3 is coded as three char codes separated by '__'.

I would like to create a new csv that replicates rows for each component of the column codes. The results should be like:

```
col1,col2,codes
1,2,aaa
1,2,bbb
2,4,aaa
2,4,eee
3,4,ccc
```

This is a fairly large file (around 10G). I would like to perform this bash (awk?) without using a programming language if possible. The actual file has about 3000 columns.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Technically, bash is a programming language, as is awk. Avoiding a compiled language, such as C or Java, is one thing, but avoiding languages like perl or python in favour of awk may not be as prudent, depending on the content of your csv file. Awk probably can do this, but it might get a bit ugly.

Comment: No one can tell you what you are doing wrong because you did not supply your code. Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Following awk command yields the desired result.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{split($NF,a,/__/);for(i in a){$NF=a[i];print}}' file
```

Comment: Assuming that column 3 never has anything like `"aaa__b,c_ddd" in it... :)

Comment: @Tanktalus I'd hope that if the fields can contain commas or newlines that the OP would have shared that with us in the posted sample input.

Comment: @oguzismail you might want to tweak it to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{n=split($NF,a,/__/);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){$NF=a[i];print}}' file` so it'll work for any number of fields and will print the output lines in the order of the values in the final field rather than random (probably hash) order.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, but, IME, it's one of those things that many people don't notice until way later.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Perl one-liner

```
$ cat joseph.txt
col1,col2,codes
1,2,aaa__bbb
2,4,aaa__eee
3,4,ccc

$ perl -F, -lane ' if($.>1) {  print "$F[0],$F[1],",$_ for(split("__",$F[2])) } ' joseph.txt
1,2,aaa
1,2,bbb
2,4,aaa
2,4,eee
3,4,ccc

$
```